# Generate quote::ToTokens for data type that already has implmented Parse trait

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Is there a way to generate a `ToTokens` impl for a data type (represents macro input) that already has an implmentation of `syn::Parse` trait and the original `TokenStream`? I want to know if there's a way to automatically do this because I don't want to write `ToTokens` for it.

`macro input` --- (Parse) ---> `my data type`

Then I make changes to `my data type` and want to write it back as a `TokenStream` representing an edited `macro input`:

`my data type added with extra data` --- (ToTokens?) ---> `new macro input`.

Comment: How would the compiler infer the `ToTokens` implementation from the `Parse` implementation? By magic? There might be a way using some crate that has stronger connection between the parsed form and the `TokenStream`, though.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The problem I am trying to solve, as you may have already inferred, is to write some code that changes (appends code) to an already existing macro (`syn::Item::Macro`). But yeah, I was hoping somehow to autogenerate the `ToTokens` impl. I guess I may have to bite the bullet and write the whole macro `ToTokens` impl which is in no way trivial for my case.